# Using CustomValidator for CheckBox ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Hi i am really struggling to set a customer validator to my checkboxes to make sure the user has to check at least one.

I have looked and looked on this site, read and tried but nothing seems to work. I am also unsure of what to code on the server side as i am still learning as a beginner so any help would be very grateful.

Please can i say i have no clue on C# so any code you suggest needs to be ASP.NET/VisualBasic

These are my check boxes HMTL side..

```
Male:
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbMale" runat="server" groupname="sexB"/> 
    <br />
Female:
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbFemale" runat="server" groupname="sexB"/>
```

Thank You

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load



    If Page.IsPostBack = False Then

        Dim dsData1 As New DataSet
        dsData1 = tableData()


        DDList.DataSource = dsData1
        DDList.DataValueField = "code"
        DDList.DataTextField = "description"
        DDList.DataBind()
        DDList.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty))
        DDList.SelectedIndex = 0


        Dim dsData2 As New DataSet
        dsData2 = tableData2()


        DDList2.DataSource = dsData2
        DDList2.DataValueField = "code"
        DDList2.DataTextField = "description"
        DDList2.DataBind()
        DDList2.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty))
        DDList2.SelectedIndex = 0
    Else


        Dim sexSelect1 As String = ""

        If cbMale.Checked = True Then
            sexSelect1 = "M"
        Else
            sexSelect1 = "F"
        End If


        Dim testInsert As String = dataInsertTable(nameB.Text, ageB.Text, sexSelect1,  DDList.SelectedValue, DDList2.SelectedValue)


    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: The if statement that shows 'cbMale' was used for a checkbox but i couldnt work out how to use a customvalidator with this. I cant seem to change the IF Statement for the new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a common scenario, You can use customvalidator the way as mentioned in this example:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Validate-ASPNet-CheckBoxList-at-least-one-CheckBox-checked-using-Custom-Validator.aspx

IT uses Javascript to validate.

Add the following in the head section

```
 <script language = javascript >
        function ValidateSE(source, args) {
            var chkSEMAFF = document.getElementById('<%= CbSe.ClientID%>');
            var chkSEMAFFX = chkSEMAFF.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 0; i < chkSEMAFFX.length; i++) {
                if (chkSEMAFFX[i].checked) {
           args.IsValid = true;
              return;
        }
      }
     // alert("Choose either male or female");
      args.IsValid = false;

}
</script>
```

Add the following between form tag

```
 <div>

    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CbSe" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

   <asp:ListItem Text="male" Value="male" /> 
   <asp:ListItem Text="female" Value="female" />
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    <asp:customvalidator runat="server" forecolor="Red" id="cuse" clientvalidationfunction="ValidateSE" errormessage="Please select either male or female"></asp:customvalidator>
  </div>
```

Add the following as code behind

```
 Dim sexSelect1 As String = ""

            If CbSe.SelectedValue = "male" Then
                sexSelect1 = "M"
            Else
                sexSelect1 = "F"
            End If
```

Comment: sorry can you tell me where i would put the <script> code please

Comment: Just let me know if you still find any issue.

Comment: Hi, yes i am having an issue with the checkboxlist as i have a function that needs to collect the data of whether male or female is selected but with this new code my if statement does not work and my page errors, i will edit my Q to show my function

Comment: Add the following in the head section of the source file <script language = javascript >
        function ValidateSE(source, args) {
            var chkSEMAFF = document.getElementById('<%= CbSe.ClientID%>');
            var chkSEMAFFX = chkSEMAFF.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 0; i < chkSEMAFFX.length; i++) {
                if (chkSEMAFFX[i].checked) {
           args.IsValid = true;
              return;
        }
      }
     // alert("Choose either male or female");
      args.IsValid = false;
      
}
</script>

Comment: add the following between form tag                                                 <div>

    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CbSe" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

   <asp:ListItem Text="male" Value="male" /> 
   <asp:ListItem Text="female" Value="female" />
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    <asp:customvalidator runat="server" forecolor="Red" id="cuse" clientvalidationfunction="ValidateSE" errormessage="Please select either male or female"></asp:customvalidator>

Comment: do let me know if you still have an issue.